# Is there a way of simplifying multiple comparison operators combined with OR in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say that I have a variable `length` which I would like to compare upon multiple values.

I want to check if `length` has the value of `0` or `1`.

```
if length == 0 or length == 1:
    pass
```

I would like to know if there is a way to shorten the above code.

Since Python supports ["comparison operator chaining"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) like `a < b < c` which is interpreted as `a < b and b < c`.

I was wondering if there is a way to shorten `a operator1 b or b operator2 c`, which are multiple comparisons combined with `or`.

Comment: `if length in [0, 1]:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```py
if length in [0,1]:
    pass
```

Now `length` is 0 or 1.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that! Thanks for the answer!